# Django star rating: mark some stars at load

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Hello I'm using this star rating widget http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/ to add functionality for users to vote on specific subject.

Sending votes uses jQuery's ajax functions to send a call to the server side. The stars are generated from the client side by the widget, but I retrieve the average score and total voters from the server side.

My question is how should I go to implement so that some stars are marked upon load for a subject that persons have voted on.

The widget itself provides it by simply using the `checked=checked` attribute. I tried by so far using jQuery to add this attribute before page load. It did added the attribute, but the widget itself was still executed first thus the checked wasn't applied.

I find that I maybe have to generate the radio buttons from server side, which will turn into an ugly solution. So I wonder how should it be done?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("[value=3]").attr("checked","checked");
}); 
$(function() {
    $('.auto-submit-star').rating({ 
        callback: function(value){ 
            //alert(value);
            $.post("/process_vote/", {u_id: u_id, rating: value, m_id: hit_id, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token}, 
                function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Maybe you're calling .rating() too early ?

Comment: @jpic It is before the .rating() call. I posted the code.

Comment: Why not move "$("[value=3]").attr("checked","checked");" just before "$('.auto-submit-star').rating({ " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("[value=3]").attr("checked","checked");
}); 
$(function() {
    $('.auto-submit-star').rating({
```

With:

```
$(function() {
    $("[value=3]").attr("checked","checked");
    $('.auto-submit-star').rating({
```

This will ensure the linearity of the process.